# Capybara - I have to click the capybara button, and he can't find

Tags: capybara

```
<button _ngcontent-c50="" class="mat-menu-item ng-star-inserted" mat-menu-item="" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false"> 11 - teste <div class="mat-menu-ripple mat-ripple" matripple=""></div></button>
```

Code Capybara, 
tested with

```
browser.find('button', text: ' 11 - teste ').click
find_button(' 11 - teste ')
find('#button.mat-menu-item').click
```

Comment: Who is "he" referring to?

Comment: What errors do you get for each of your attempts?

Answer (score 2):

With that HTML you should just be able to use

```
click_button('11 - teste')
```

If not provide the exact error message you get

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly finding a button with the text you specified?

```
find('button', text: '11 - teste')
```

Depending upon your version of Capybara, you could also specify that it is the search is *not exact*:

```
find('button', text: '11 - teste', exact_text: false)
```

Comment: Thank you it worked like this
find('button', text: '11', exact_text: false).click